# I don't understand why the function set in apscheduler is unintentionally executed 3 times in Django

Tags: python, django, apscheduler

I am creating a web app with Django.
I wrote the following codes to add 1 data per minute to the table using APScheduler. When I checked the data generated by APScheduler on the Django admin panel, I found that 3 data were generated per minute for some reason.
why does this happen? and how can i solve it?

```
# models.py
from django.db import models
class Test(models.Model):
    test = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

```
# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Test
class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('test', 'created_at')

admin.site.register(Test, TestAdmin)
```

```
# ap_scheduler.py
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from .models import Test

def myfunc():
    Test.objects.create(test='test')

def start():
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(myfunc, 'cron', second=50)
    scheduler.start()
```

```
# apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig
class MembersConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'my_app_name'
    
    def ready(self):
        from .ap_scheduler import start
        start()
```

#### バージョン情報

```
APScheduler==3.9.1
Django==4.0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have multiple schedulers due to the auto-reloader is calling the start() command more then once.  Try running with:

```
python manage.py runserver --noreload
```

Comment: Can I use this command in production environment?
Sorry for the lack of explanation. When I run this APScheduler locally, it works fine, but when I publish it with gnicorn and nginx on AWS EC2, it runs 3 times.
When I run `~$ ps ax | grep gunicorn`, I see 4 processes like below. Is it related to what you said?
`1577 ? Sl 0:02 /home/ubuntu/djangoenv/bin/python /home/ubuntu/djangoenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind /home/ubuntu/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx.sock xxxxxxxx.wsgi:application`

Comment: yes, you can do that,  autoreload is a setting only meant for devlopers.

Comment: Do you mean the command `python manage.py runserver --noreload` can be used in production? I tried it, but nothing changed.

Comment: After investigating a little more, it seems that the number of workers in the service file is related.
When ExecStart of `/etc/systemd/system/my_project_name.service` is set to "--worker 1" or --preload option is added, only one data is generated.

`ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/my_project_name/virtual_env_name/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --preload --bind /home/ubuntu/my_project_name/my_project_name.sock my_project_name.wsgi:application`

Comment: good find.  you are probably going to want to separate the scheduler from django.  you don't want to limit django to a single worker if you have any significant volume of http traffic.